# how to use split to get the middle value which retrieve from datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

hihi 
i have a question that i want to ask about c#  and window form

1. i have this data... A,B,C; A1,B1,C1; A2,B2,C2; (this data is not hardcoded, it can continue to change, when more data insert come in) , i select this database column which is name as ColABC , and i retrieve and put in the datagridview , 
   So is possible to always get the middle data?....but it is always this format record1 data, record1 data, record1; record2 data, record3 data, record...and **so i want this data all  the middle value retrieve out to this become this B,B1,B2.......so on...**

   ```
   ID |  ColABC
    1 |  A,B,C; A1,B1,C1; A2,B2,C2;
   ```

This is like my `DataGridView`, the above.

The only thing i know is use split by `;` first then by `,`.

Is there any direct way?

Something like this, I try:

```
string[] doll = null;
doll = Convert.ToString(DGV.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value).Split(';');
```

Basically like example the above code, doll get the  " A,B,C; A1,B1,C1; A2,B2,C2; " this data which i retrieve from datagridview, so if i declare roll[0] it will give me "A,B,C", like what i mention above the data will change so how am i get the middle value always??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var input = "A,B,C; A1,B1,C1; A2,B2,C2;";
var resultList = Regex.Matches(input, @".*?,(.*?),.*?;")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(arg => arg.Groups[1].Value)
    .ToList();

var firstValue = resultList[0];
var secondValue = resultList[1];

// bind to a combobox
comboBox1.DataSource = resultList;

var comaSeparatedString = string.Join(",", resultList);
```

Comment: But this data is take from datagridview , still can directly put in the input? like the code i give the i will only get the result of A,B,C if i ask for roll[0]

Comment: @Alex the problem is i don't know how or don't any example, but i can say more detail in my question

Comment: @Alex take a look see whether after i explain out , are you able to update to the question

Comment: ya, i need the result as a string cause i need to place B,B1,B2 in a label, in c# can declare var?

Comment: @Alex , if later on, i need to take from resultString each value like example B only, can show me in another separate code how should i do it....i scare later i need to use it

Comment: @Alex is it possible to put resultList in a comobox in  window, so that user able to can selected either B or B1 or B2.....is it possible?

Comment: @Alex where is the datasource property ....do i need to write any code beside that.... then about this if later on, i need to take from resultString each value like example B only, can show me in another separate code how should i do it....i scare later i need to use it...which i ask you

Comment: @Alex can i ask another question is...i change your var input = "A,B,C; A1,B1,C1; A2,B2,C2;";        to       var input = Convert.ToString(DGV_I2RMS_UpdateNominalRoll.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value); ...it work but it only if i click on the next row, the combobox still remain as the first row b1,b2,b3...how to change it according to the row change

Comment: When row is changed, parse the value `CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value` again and set `comboBox.DataSource` again.

Comment: @Alex where should i put it at??cause i dont get what you say

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you need to updated the combobox whenever another row is selected, right? If so you need to subscribe to `DataGridView.SelectionChanged`, and put your code inside of this event. So whenever selection is changed current row will be parsed and combobox will be repopulated.

Answer (score 0):

```
string testString = "A,B,C; A1,B1,C1; A2,B2,C2;";

Regex rgx = new Regex("[^,]+,([^,]+),[^,]+");
List<string> whatYouWant = testString.Split(';').Select(a => rgx.Replace(a, "$1")).ToList();
```

or

```
string testString = "A,B,C; A1,B1,C1; A2,B2,C2;";

Regex rgx = new Regex("[^,;]+,([^,;]+),[^,;]+;?");

for(Match m = rgx.Match(testString); m.Success; m = m.NextMatch())
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Comment: the data is i retrieve from datagirdview is not hardcoded, still can put in testString...as what i mention to Alex in another answer, like the code i give the i will only get the result of A,B,C if i ask for roll[0]

Answer (score 0):

What about this....  Not in my device, to test this code... Still this is the approach...

```
  foreach(DataGridViewRow dgvr in Datagridview.Rows){

  if(dgvr!=null){
  string middlevalues="";
  string testString=      dgvr.Cells[ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
  //If this string is string testString = "A,B,C; A1,B1,C1; A2,B2,C2;";
  string[] basesplit = testString.Split(';');
  int i=0;
  foreach(string words in baseplit){
  if(i<baseplit.Count-1){
  middlevalues=words.Split(',')[1].ToString()+','
  }else{       middlevalues=words.Split(',')[1].ToString();
  i++;
  }
  }
  }


  }
```